# Undefined control sequence (\email, \address) in combine class

Tags: combine

I am using the combine class to merge several tex files. Each of these files has a title with the name of the article, name of the author and the author's address and email id. Here is a sample of each article:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}

\title[xxx]{xxx}

\author{yyy}

\address{Department of zzz, www}

\email{abc@gmail.com}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

...

\end{abstract}

...

\end{document}
```

Here is the text from the main document for the combine:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{combine}

\begin{document}

 \pagestyle{combine}

 \maketitle \tableofcontents

 \clearpage

 
 \begin{papers}

  \coltoctitle{xxx}

  \coltocauthor{yyy}

  \label{abc}

  \import{abc}

\end{papers}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile the main combine file, I get the following error:

> ./abc.tex:Undefined control sequence \address
>
> ./abc.tex:Undefined control sequence \email

The individual articles do not give this error. Will be grateful for help on this! Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm new to TeX.SE and still trying to figure things out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `combine` class needs to know which document classes you are using in imported documents.

This can be passed as an option at loading time: `memoir`, `book`, `report`, and `letter` can be passed directly, while, if you don't specify anything, `article` is assumed.

In your case you are using `amsart`, and to let `combine` know about it, you have to pass the option `colclass=amsart`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,colclass=amsart]{combine}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,colclass=amsart]{combine}

\title{Proceedings}

\begin{document}

 \pagestyle{combine}

 \maketitle \tableofcontents

 \clearpage


 \begin{papers}

  \coltoctitle{xxx}

  \coltocauthor{yyy}

  \label{abc}

  \import{abc}

\end{papers}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]